# batch script to copy files from all available drives to a USB

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have this script

```
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
    copy "%%x\*.spt" "%drive%\mydiagtools"
)
pause
```

and I need it to copy files with SPT extension (our proprietary company files) to my USB drive from all available disks on a specific computer.

Any idea anyone why is it not working?
This the output I get:

```
F:\>for /F "skip=1 delims=" %x in
*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
The device is not ready.

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
\*.spt
The filename, directory name, or v
        0 file(s) copied.

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
The device is not ready.

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
The device is not ready.

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
\*.spt
The filename, directory name, or v
        0 file(s) copied.

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
\*.spt
The system cannot find the path sp
        0 file(s) copied.

\*.spt" "\mydiagtools" )
\*.spt
The filename, directory name, or v
        0 file(s) copied.

F:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Thank you very much

edit: corrected the output

Comment: Where is %drive% defined?

Comment: Are you trying to copy files located in any folder on every drive? Because this script is only going to copy files located in the root folder, once it is fixed. Being you are limited to a maximum of 26 drives on Windows and I doubt you have anywhere near that many, why don’t you just re-use a simple one-liner command with `xcopy` or `robocopy` to do this manually on the few drives you have?

Comment: @mt025 I'm not sure where %drive% is defined, I suppose it's an environmental variable labelling the USB drive or the drive wherefrom the batch file is executed . It works when I do `copy "c:\fielfor.spt" "%drive%\mydiagtools"`
@Appleoddity Yes, I'm trying to copy files located in any folder on every drive to a specific folder on my USB drive. We have many computers and every computer has different number of drives and their letters vary as well.

Answer (score 0):

would you like to use powershell? Please try the following script.

```
$copy=Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem  |  %{ Get-ChildItem $_.Root -Recurse -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.spt'}} Copy-Item -Path $copy.Fullname -Destination  C:\xxxx\
```

At the end of the script, please modified to be your USB, then run as powershell.

Comment: I don't want to use powershell I gotta use the regular command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
    copy "%%x\*.spt" "%drive%\mydiagtools"
)
pause
```

Despite `%drive%` not holding any value for me, the problem appeared to be related to `delims=`. Without it, i could successfully list and copy a drive's contents, whereas `delims=` caused an unwanted side effect to not show or copy any files.

(tested under Windows 10 Enterprise x64 version 1803 build 10.0.**17134.376**)